# Relation between the diagonalization of a matrix and of its sub-block

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a symmetric matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ whose diagonalization is known:
$$
M = R D R'
$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $R'$ is the transpose of $R$.
Now I take a squared sub-block of $M$, considering only the first $n<k$ columns and rows, $M_n$.

Is there any known result that relates the diagonalization of $M$ with the one of $M_n$?

I have the feeling that the eigenvalues of $M_n$ should be related to those of $M$.

Comment: This property isn't called diagonalizability in general, but rather [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) with a diagonal matrix.

Comment: ... unless $R$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

By the [min-max principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem), if the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\lambda_1 \le \ldots \le \lambda_k$ and the eigenvalues of $M_n$ are
$\mu_1 \le \ldots \le \mu_n$ (both counted by multiplicity), then $\lambda_i \le \mu_i \le \lambda_{k-n+i}$.